# How can I send the Object class to server with Jackson?

Tags: java, android, json, casting, jackson

I have a Message class like this:

```
class Message {
   @JsonProperty("content")
   Object content;
}
```

where the content attribute can be a `User`, a `Post`, or a `String`
and I have to send this object to the server and cast the content to the right class.

I'm using Jackson annotations to serialize the JSON, but when I try to cast the content, an error appears, because the attribute content arrives in the server like a `LinkedHashMap` object.

The error is:

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MegaRadarSocial].[Resteasy]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to br.com.megaradar.megaradarsocial.model.User
```

I would like a help to casting...
Thanks

Comment: Please post all relevant parts of your code. What Jackson annotations do you use? What error do you get?

Comment: Jackson doesn't do content based deserialization. You are going to have to handle the mapping of the incoming JSON to types yourself.

Comment: How can I do this map? Could you show me the right way?

Comment: @Perception Jackson can do polymorphic handling, however, by adding additional type information

Comment: @StaxMan - the classes the OP is using are only as polymorphic as their extension from java.lang.Object. Example 6 in the tutorial you linked is an example of the custom due serialization the OP is going to have to do.

Comment: Right, but what I meant is that Jackson lets one do this with annotations (or even without, with "default typing"); so you do NOT have to handle mapping manually, unless you can not allow inclusion of type info in JSON.

Comment: @StaxMax - ok I re-read your answer and just noticed the part about including the type info in the incoming JSON package. This shifts the burden of customization to the client (need to include an identifier in the JSON packets), but the OP may be ok with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. But I found another way to convert my Object to any type I want.
I'm using the method `convertValue` from the `ObjectMapper` object. Then, I can simulate the casting.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As you control both ends (server and client), you could try Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/. One of its features allows you to serialize to json and type information, this enables you to deserialize back to the right type.

```
Genson genson = new Genson.Builder().setWithClassMetadata(true).create();
json = genson.serialize(yourMessage);

// then deserialize it back
Message message = genson.deserialize(json, Message .class);
```

The serialized json will look like : {"content": {"@class":"package.path.Message", ...the object values...}}

You can even define aliases for the serialized classes

```
new Genson.Builder().addAlias("message", Message.class)
```

**Important**: Note that you need to use the same configuration of genson on both sides. So enable type information with setWithClassMetadata and if you use aliases, you must define the same on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation, like so:

```
class Message {
 @JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY property="type")
 @JsonProperty("content")
 Object content;
}
```

(you can see http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html for examples)

which would add property "type" with class name as value (there are many alternative ways as well) when serializing, and using that when deserializing.